# two edittext and one button on the same line

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have to place two edittext and a button on the same line.
The two edittext should have the same width, the largest possible so to fill the line. The button should be on the right.
It should be like this:
Edittext_______________________ EditText_________________________  Button
I post some relative code, which for the moment is not working.

```
        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/new_formulas"
    >
    <Button
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        />
    <EditText
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/add_hint"
        android:id="@+id/add_hint2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        />

    <EditText
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/add_hint"
        android:id="@+id/add_hint"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your target schema

Comment: use linear layout and set it to horizontal

Comment: @cwfei I can't because such a row is part of a more complex scheme, so the layout should be relative.

Comment: then add a linear layout inside the relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/new_formulas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_hint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:hint="Hint"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_hint2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add_hint"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:hint="hint2"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add_hint2"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't insert a linear layout inside a relative layout for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Try following Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="User"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Pass"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Click"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't insert a linear layout inside a relative layout for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linear Layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/new_formulas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_hint2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/add_hint"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_hint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/add_hint"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the layout should be Relative for other reasons

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_formulas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_hint2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/add_hint"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_hint"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:hint="@string/add_hint"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textSize="30dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

You can adjust weight acoording to your need but remember sum of all weight must be 100

Comment: You can use relativeLayout as parent layout for this linear layout

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) from the new [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html). It inherits all the alignment attributes of RelativeLayout and lets you specify dimensions and margins in percentages. Basically a counterpart of the layout_weight attribute of LinearLayout. Read [Joanna Smith's #proTip](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/C8oaLunpEEj) for more info.

First add the dependency in app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.1'
}
```

Then change your code like this:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/new_formulas">

    <Button
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add" />

    <EditText
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_hint" />

    <EditText
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add_hint"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_hint2" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Some tips:

- Use sp instead of dp for textSize
- Always format the code (ctrl + alt + L) before posting. Makes it more readable.

Comment: if I do what you advice, the "app:layout_widthPercent" is not recognized at compiling time

Comment: Have you added the dependency? Also add the app namespace `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your root layout.

Comment: I have the following problem: "Gradle DSL method not found". Yes I have added the dependency.

Comment: Did you remove `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` from app/build.gradle ? Do not remove/replace anything. Just add `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.1'` at the end.

Comment: And make sure you're editing build.gradle that is under the app folder, not in the root project folder.

Comment: I have this in the app/build.gradle : 
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: Should I add "    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.1'
" inside the depencencies here?

Comment: No, that's not the file you should be editing. Search for the other build.gradle file. It is inside the app folder.

Comment: sorry but in the app folder there is no build.gradle file. I have two of these files inside the gradle scripts..

Comment: That's weird. Actually your build.gradle file should look like this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/blob/master/app/build.gradle , and you should add the dependencies in the `dependency { }` block at the bottom.

Comment: ok sorry I have found it, but I have the same problem in compiling even if I add the dependency. maybe my system doesn't support the percent?

Comment: Oh wait, have you not updated the Android Support Library in your SDK Manager? :) Sorry I assumed you had the latest version. Please always keep it updated. The latest version is 23.0.1 as of today.

Comment: And please consider going though Udacity's Android courses. They are really good for beginners like us. :) Good day, and happy coding!